# How to refer to the position where you bend to the floor with your hands covering your head?

Tags: single-word-requests

So basically, the position you take while hiding under a table during an earthquake. I think it was something starting with "clu" or "cru"." Of course, I could be mistaken.

Answer (score 18):

During the Cold war, in the USA, this movement was called "[duck and cover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_and_cover)".

It was popularized in [this public service video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IKqXu-5jw60).

---

This video was made for atomic bomb damage mitigation, not earthquakes – but you may find the term applicable.

You might simply consider the verb, to "**duck**"

Comment: so "ducked under the table" is more common than "crouched under the table?"

Comment: Heh, +1 for a historical perspective. @janoChen the two are different. To _duck_ under something is to quickly move under it, to _crouch_ under something carries no implication of movement. In other words, you can _crouch under the table all day_ but you cannot really _duck under the table all day_.

Comment: @janoChen Yes.  A "duck" here is an inherently defensive action.  A "crouch" does not inherently carry that connotation of protection.  I can *crouch* in order to then leap to an attack.

Comment: Ducked under the table refers to moving quickly to get under the table. Once you've ducked under the table, you remain there crouching under the table.

Comment: In the late 1960s, those of us who had lived through the Cold War elementary school rehearsals of *duck and cover* response to a nuclear attack transformed it to *Sit on the floor, put your head between your knees, and kiss your ass goodbye!*

Comment: A slightly late regeneration merely called it *shelter drills*.

Comment: As I remember from my (1960s) childhood, the "atomic scare" days were during the COLD War (against the Russians). The atomic bomb ended World War II.

Answer (score 12):

I think you are looking for [*crouch*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/crouch) but that is not specific to an earthquake nor to covering your head:

> crouch  (krouch) 
> v. crouched, crouch·ing, crouch·es 
> v.intr. 
> 1a. To stoop, especially with the knees bent: crouched over the grate, searching for his keys. 
> 1b. To press the entire body close to
> the ground with the limbs bent: a cat crouching near its prey.
>
>  2. To bend servilely or timidly; cringe. 
> v.tr. To bend (the head or knee, for example) low, as in fear or humility.
> n. The act or posture
> of bending low or crouching.

In the context of airplane safety instructions at least, the position you describe is called [*brace position*](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/brace-position):

> a position for an emergency landing of a plane, where the passenger sits bent forward with their hands behind their head

Answer (score 5):

The current suggestions of ***duck*** and ***crouch*** imply to me that you would still primarily have your feet on the ground with most of your body just off the ground.

While I don't know what position one would take during an earthquake, I wonder whether you might be more *lying* on the ground under the table, in which case, you may:

- ***curl up*** (into a ball)
- adopt the ***foetal*** *(BrE)* / ***fetal*** *(AmE)* position

Comment: Though with the foetal position, I wouldn't think of your hands covering your head as in the 'brace' position.

Comment: @anotherdave Thanks - I knew there was a word for that, but couldn't think of it. But can you use *brace position* if you're lying on the floor and not sitting in an aeroplane seat?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure alright — I'm just thinking that the foetal position might be discounted by the hands above the head (can't picture that baby :) )

Comment: IMO, lying down is not a good strategy for staying safe in an earthquake.  Laying = *prone* due to the reduced motility.  not a survival tactic.  Fetal-position is generally a posture of surrender (submission / zero-threat)